# Why some websites preload CSS immediately before declaring it?

Tags: html, css, performance

I noticed on multiple websites that they preload the CSS (using rel="preload") immediately before loading it normally (using rel="stylesheet").

Here is an example from vercel.com

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/media/c9a5bc6a7c948fb0-s.p.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin="anonymous" data-next-font="size-adjust"/>
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/834c693f73f8a310.css?dpl=dpl_7X1gBUozydx7F9WQkRbor8tutgFy" as="style"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/834c693f73f8a310.css?dpl=dpl_7X1gBUozydx7F9WQkRbor8tutgFy" data-n-g=""/>
```

- Here on the first line, they're preloading a font file, which makes sense, you don't want to wait on the CSS before starting to load the fonts
- Line 2 preloading the CSS file, and line 3 loading the same CSS file. Here I don't understand what's the benefit of preloading.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: It tells the browser to give it higher priority which eventually leads to better chaching and mainly, to improve the site's performance when loading. To be detailed, it makes it start loading the stylsheet as soon as possible, it doesn't wait for the main rendering process

Comment: @Robin270 Your statement is partially incorrect. Please see my answer.

Comment: @JensT You made me unsure, I had to google it but found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload)

Comment: Yes, this is the mdn page that explains how preload works, nevertheless in the specific case, the author of the question posted, it has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case it is redundant. (It is a known next.js problem.) To be more specific: Preloading ressources never changes the fetch priority, it uses the same default priority (in this case "highest" which is the default for render blocking css). It only starts the download earlier, if the ressource is hidden from the browsers (look-ahead) ressource scanner. I.e. when the ressource is defined in a css file. In the case you posted, the browser will discover both tags at the same time, so the preload tag only bloats the html.